# How to get the values of sub objects of json objects while using object.key method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

By using an api and getting a response .In response, i have got the list of objects in deals named object and the count of these object is 19 .I have used the below function to get the 'keys' and 'values' of each object.But some keys which is ultimately an object has sub object that contains keys and values ,i have tried but i m unable to access them.I have given below the snippet of response of an api call.Here I'm able to access the object at index 0's active  but for business i got [object object] because it has keys and values inside it i.e 'id',that i'm unable to access ,i want to access them too.

```
 meta: Object
       response: Object
           deals: Array[20]
                0: Object
                    active: 1
                    business: Object
                       id: 608290.....
```

Below is the function  to get the keys as well as values of all the objects

```
function getAllobjectData(data) {
    $.each(data.response.deals, function (i, deals) {
        console.log("value of index " + i);
        var keys = [],
            values = [];
        $.each(deals, function (key, value) {
            keys.push(key);
            values.push(value);
            var subkey = [],
                subvalue = [];
```

This part i add and tried to get the subobjects keys and values but it didnt work and i dont know is this a correct way.

```
$.each(key, function (subkey, subvalue) {                          <-------------      
                    alert(subkey + ": " + subkey);                              -
                });                                                             -
                console.log('subkey ' + (i + 1) + ' is ' + subkey);             - 
                console.log('subvalue ' + (i + 1) + ' is ' + subvalue);         -
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
            });
            console.log('keys ' + (i + 1) + ' is ' + subkey);
            console.log('values ' + (i + 1) + ' is ' + subvalue);

        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve this elegantly is to use [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29).

Here's an example of a function that will return an array of arrays in the form of `[keyPath, value]`:

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/RQuBD/1/**

```
function collectSimpleValues(data, values, path) {  
    path = path || '';
    values = values || [];

    Object.keys(data).forEach(function (k) {
        var p = path + k, v = data[k];

        if (typeof v === 'object') collectSimpleValues(v, values, p + '.');
        else values.push([p, v]);
    });

    return values;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what exactly is your need, but if you just want to access the objects under deals array, you can modify your function as below

```
function getAllobjectData(data) {
    $.each(data.response.deals, function (i, deal) {
        console.log("value of index " + i);
        var keys = [],
            values = [];
        // since you are already looping through deals, no need to create another loop
        console.log(deal.active); //should output 1
        console.log(deal.business.id); should output 608290
        // and so on...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to utilize recursion here (if you do not know the depth of the object).

```
var meta = {
   response: {
       deals: [
            {
                active: 1,
                business: {
                   id: 608290
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};

// print object
printValue(meta);

function printValue( oValue, sKey )
{
    if( typeof oValue == 'object' || typeof oValue == 'array' )
    {
        for( i in oValue )
        {
            console.log( i + ' is an object' );
            printValue( oValue[i], i );
        }

    }
    else
        console.log( sKey, oValue );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't have to keep changing your parameters on .each(). Every time you call that function, you can just use `(k, v)` and params k && v will apply to whatever is inside that function unless you use them again in another .each().

I'm not sure you're exact JSON or expected result, but I through together a little fiddle that might help show you how easy "deep diving" can be.

Also, don't forget JavaScript's typeof method if you're not sure if a value might be a "string" or "object". FYI, array's could show as "objects" too, if you want difference there use `instanceof`. Although you can use Objects and Arrays pretty similarly throughout JavaScript. For instance `someArray["someKey"]` works just like `someObject["someKey"]`

Anyway, on with the long fiddle:

### jsFiddle

### Example of some of the code:

```
var TopLevel_keys = new Array(), TopLevel_values = new Array(), ulTop = $("<ul />", { class: "level-top" }).appendTo($("body"));
$.each(bob, function(k, v) {
    TopLevel_keys.push(k); TopLevel_values.push(v);
    ulTop.append($("<li />", { text: k }));

    var Level01_keys = new Array(), Level01_values = new Array(), ul01 = $("<ul />", { class: "level-01" }).appendTo(ulTop.children("li").last());
    $.each(v, function(k, v) {
        Level01_keys.push(k); Level01_values.push(v);
        ul01.append($("<li />", { text: k }));

        var Level02_keys = new Array(), Level02_values = new Array(), ul02 = $("<ul />", { class: "level-02" }).appendTo(ul01.children("li").last());
        $.each(v, function(k, v) {
            Level02_keys.push(k); Level02_values.push(v);
            ul02.append($("<li />", { text: k }));

            etc ...
```